# React component doesn't rerender based onprops change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf-viewer

I have pdf-viewer component

```
export default function PDFViewer({keyword}) {
    const searchPluginInstance = searchPlugin({
        keyword,
    })
    const {Search} = searchPluginInstance;
  return (
    <div>
        <Search/>
        <Viewer plugins={[searchPluginInstance]} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

`keyword` is an array of strings that are passed down to the component. That passed keyword list is highlighted in the pdf doc that is the function. But this works only for the first render cycle. After I update the keyword in the parent component and pass it here, nothing is happening.

Basically, once it creates the `searchPluginInstance` instance, It won't change based on the props changes. I don't know how to address thing issue? Is there a design pattern or something to handle this issue?

[This is the libray](https://react-pdf-viewer.dev/)

Answer (score 1):

I think,

You should make sure that the `keyword` passed down to `PDFViewer` component has to  be a react `state` if you want to rerender the `PDFViewer` when `keyword state` changes.

might be you are doing something like that -

```
function ParentComponent() {
   let keyword = [...]
   return (
     <PDFViewer keyword={keyword} />
   )
}
```

Try this -

```
function ParentComponent() {
   const [keyword, setKeyword] = setState(arr);
   return (
     <PDFViewer keyword={keyword} />
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to add the parent component code too so that we can check.

Some suggestions:

1. Make sure you are passing props that are new objects so React can detect the changes.
2. Try a stripped-down version of the parent and child component code and see if it works.